# написать функцию преобразования строки в массив подстрок определенной длины с помощью reduce

Tags: javascript, массивы

Даны строка, например, `str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` и длина подстроки `nmb`.

Необходимо написать функцию `(str, nmb) => {}` которая преобразует строку в массив подстрок, длина которых равна `nmb`.
Решил через обычный цикл, но необходимо через `reduce`

```js
let str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; //
let strToArr = str.split('');
console.log(strToArr)
let nmb = 6;

function dividedArr(str, nmb) {
  let mc = Math.ceil(str.length / nmb)
  let arr = []
  let start = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < mc; i++) {
    arr[i] = str.slice(start, start + nmb)
    start += nmb
  }
  console.log(arr)
}

dividedArr(str, 3)
dividedArr(str, 5)
```

Используя `reduce` смог решить частично: формируется один элемент массива с заданным количеством символов `nmb` в элементе:

```js
let str = 'abcdefgh'; //ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
let nmb = 4
let arr = str.split('')
console.log(arr)
let i = 0
let arr2 = []

let result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (i < nmb) {
    acc += item
    i++
  }
  return acc
}, [])
arr2.push(result)

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы не засорять ответ неоптимальным решением, можете посмотреть [правки к этому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1190741/revisions).

В общем, можно изначально посчитать количество частей и в функции `reduce` находить индекс елемента, в который нужно записывать букву. Индекс ищем с помощью такой операции `Math.floor(ind / len)`, где `ind` - числа от 0 до `str.length - 1`, `len` - длинна части. Соответственно (если подставить числа), индексы будут такие `0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 и тд.`, если `len = 4`.

```js
const str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const len = 4;

console.log(Array.from(str).reduce((acc, cur, ind) => {
  acc[Math.floor(ind / len)] += cur;
  return acc;
}, Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(str.length / len) }, () => '' )));
// Тут мы просто сразу синициализировали массив ['', '', '', '', ...]
```

Comment: жесть конечно :-D

Comment: теперь как надо, первый раз при выполнении кода был немного другой результат. Спасибо!

Comment: чтобы изначально знать количество элементов в массиве нашел выход присвоив переменной mc = Math.ceil(str.length / nmb), может это было лишнее движение конечно...

Comment: @entithat: позвольте уточнить для себя - _"Изначально мы не знаем сколько будет частей по n букв"_ Не знаем где - вне или внутри `reduce`?

Comment: @entithat: а как же четвёртый параметр в `reduce` - собственно сам исходный массив? У него есть длина и мы знаем размер для одной части, а следовательно и количество частей можно высчитывать внутри `reduce`. Мне просто интересно.

Answer (score 0):

так устроит?

```
arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (i < nmb) {
        acc += item
        i++
    }
    else {
        arr2.push(acc)
        i = 0
        acc = ''
    }
    return acc
}, [])
```

или вот такой вариант - без лишних внешних переменных

```
arr2 = arr.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    if (acc[acc.length - 1].length < nmb) {
        acc[acc.length - 1] += item
    }
    else {
        acc[acc.length] = item
    }
    
    // избавиться от последнего элемента массива, если его размер меньше nmb
    if ((index === arr.length - 1) && (acc[acc.length - 1].length !== nmb)) {
        acc.pop();
    }
    
    return acc
}, [''])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[...str].reduce((r,c)=>{ 
  if (r[r.length-1].length==4) {
    r.push("");
  } 
  r[r.length-1]+=c; 
  return r;
},[""]);
```

А можно проще без reduce:

```
str.split(/(.{4})/g).filter(s=>s)
```

На тему split еще вариант:

```
str.replace(/.{4}/g,'$&,').split(',')
```

Или вот еще через map:

```
new Array(Math.ceil(str.length/4)).fill().map((v,i)=>str.substr(i*4,4))
```

Comment: спасибо! Нужен именно reduce

Comment: @RomanRytov, Я надеюсь, вы понимаете, что задача нетривиальная. Решать задачу по преобразованию строки используя метод reduce(), который для этого не предназначается, и вообще это метод из класса Array не String. Напомнило мне еврейскую мудрость. Сколько нужно евреев чтобы поменять лампочку? - три: один держит лампочку, а двое табуретку вращают. Хорошо бы, если в реальных задачах вы так не будете делать.